# Nivo Slider Not Displaying Properly

Tags: jquery, css, nivo-slider

Running into an issue with a Nivo Slider

When loading the website originally, the slider loads fine and reacts properly. When navigating to another page and then back to the slider page, it does not load.

I tried adding a random number function to the CSS and JS files associated to try and eliminate cacheing however this did not resolve the issue -- Any spot getting hung up that you can think of?

Website link: Removed

Let me know what code you would like to see if any.

Thank You for your help

Comment: [You're not closing your CSS `link` tags properly](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hearthandhomeshoppe.com%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).  Otherwise, your site is working perfectly fine here.

Comment: Random Number Function Fixed issue in FireFox, still having problem in IE

Comment: IE's cache is always stubborn and each separate page needs a hard refresh.  You probably won't see any issues if you try Explorer on a different machine.

Comment: I hear you sir, however I have three users confirming issues on different machines and browsers as we speak -- Problem is still IE at this point -- Thanks for your feedback though

Comment: You really got me curious so I fired up your site in IE8, and again, I'm not seeing the issue.  Please edit your post to include which browsers and versions.

Comment: Fixed the Issue in Firefox with the php rand Function after the JS and CSS estensions however the issue remained in IE because of the slider.xml file being called from the Nivo JS file. Added the following code in the Nivo JS file, to fix the issue in IE

 var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
 var xml = 'slider.xml' + "?" + randomNumber;

Thanks Again

Comment: Can't answer my own question given my reputation, so I was forced to comment the answer -- Will try and remember to come back 6 hours from now and answer properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the Issue in Firefox with the php rand Function after the JS and CSS estensions however the issue remained in IE because of the slider.xml file being called from the Nivo JS file. Added the following code in the Nivo JS file, to fix the issue in IE

```
var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
var xml = 'slider.xml' + "?" + randomNumber;
```

Thanks Again